# Clicking a button doesn't do anything in CasperJS

Tags: javascript, click, casperjs

I'm trying to automate the following site: http://www.1800flowers.com/orchids/purple-mini-101006?categoryId=400065010

My code is:

```
var casper = require("casper").create();
var mouse = require("mouse").create(casper);

var casper = require('casper').create({
    verbose: true,
    //logLevel: 'debug',     // debug, info, warning, error
    clientScripts: ["includes/jquery.min.js"],
    pageSettings:{
        loadImages: false,
        loadPlugins: false,
        userAgent: 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2486.0 Safari/537.36 Edge/13.10586'
    }
}
);

var fs = require('fs');

casper.start().thenOpen("http://www.1800flowers.com/orchids/purple-mini-101006?categoryId=400065010", function(){
    console.log("Access Site 1800.Com");
    this.wait(10000);
});

casper.then(function(){
    this.capture("1800_1.png");
});

casper.then(function(){
    this.evaluate(function(){
        $('#zipCode').attr('value', '12345');
        $('#locationCode').attr('value', 'Residence');

        //document.querySelector('select[id="locationCode"]').focus();
    });
    this.mouse.click('#calendarLink');
    this.wait(20000);
    this.mouse.click('#DeliveryCalendarGPTDayCharges');
    this.wait(20000);
    //this.sendEvent('keypress', this.page.event.key.Down);
});

casper.then(function(){
    this.capture("1800_2.png");
    console.log(this.getCurrentUrl());
});

casper.run();
```

Result I got

**Picture 1:**

> [image]

**Picture 2:**

> [image]

**Look at the pictures. You can see, my code working it work with 2 input (Zipcode and location type). And it clicked for show popup**. And now my problems appear. I don't know to make it click a box in popup (this is box have days available for shipping)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`casper.mouse.click` is not an asynchronous step function, but `casper.wait` is asynchronous. Which means that it is executed in this order:

```
this.evaluate(function(){ ... });
this.mouse.click('#calendarLink');
this.mouse.click('#DeliveryCalendarGPTDayCharges');
this.wait(20000);
this.wait(20000);
```

which might not be enough time of the dynamic page for the second click to have any effect. You need to put those clicks in separate steps:

```
this.evaluate(function(){ ... });
this.mouse.click('#calendarLink');
this.wait(20000, function(){
    this.mouse.click('#DeliveryCalendarGPTDayCharges');
});
this.wait(20000);
```

or shorter:

```
this.evaluate(function(){ ... });
this.thenClick('#calendarLink')
    .wait(20000)
    .thenClick('#DeliveryCalendarGPTDayCharges')
    .wait(20000);
```

Here is a more robust example with appropriate `wait*` functions:

```
this.thenClick('#calendarLink')
    .waitUntilVisible('#TB_window', function(){
        this.capture("1800_popup.png");
    }, null, 60000)
    .thenClick('#DeliveryCalendarGPTDayCharges')
    .waitWhileVisible('#TB_window', null, null, 60000);
```

Here `'#TB_window'` means the modal that is opened after the first click and closed after the second click.

Comment: it not work with me. If i try on console of firefox is
 $('#DeliveryCalendarGPTDayCharges').click(); => it work 100%. 
But on casperjs 
this.mouse.click("#DeliveryCalendarGPTDayCharges"); 
or 
$('#DeliveryCalendarGPTDayCharges').click(); => Dont have anything when i capture, picture still show popup calander. 

Can you access my site and test it ? Please help me. I try hard long time 3 - 4 days, but dont have anything come with me :(

Comment: It works for me with CasperJS 1.1-beta5 and PhantomJS 2.1.1.

Comment: Oh thank you ! now it work with me, sorry my network have problems, so it need more long time.

Comment: Can you help me, write a code waitting for popup show (#DeliveryCalendarGPTDayCharges)  and wait for (#calendarLink) ? I'm newbie, i need real example for learning. Thank you !

Comment: I've added a more robust example. If this solved your issue, you can [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/266187) the answer. Please go through your earlier questions and see if you can accept any of those answers.

Comment: Thank you. I have a question. If i want wait 2 element . I write this, right ? Or have other way shorter ? http://notepad.cc/shortcapser <= link view code

Comment: If you look closely into my code and your code, you should see that all steps are chained. You don't need to nest multiple asynchronous step functions, but you can.

Comment: 60000 in your code this is maximum time for wait ? right ?

Comment: Yes, exactly. A minute might be too much, so you can play around with it. It's also possible to set this timeout globally in the `casper.options`

Comment: http://notepad.cc/shortcapser2 see code, i trying click button add to cart and wait for a other mess show. 
But i got error "[error] [phantom] Wait timeout of 60000ms expired, exiting.
Wait timeout of 60000ms expired, exiting."

Comment: I don't get how you've found `#inlineCartWrap`, but I don't see it.

Comment: When you click "add to cart" will have popup and i use firebug for find it. Hmmm if i wrong, you can find for yourself

Comment: When I click "add to cart" the whole page reloads and the cart is shown. Remember that some pages behave differently depending on the browser.